# Фоновая отправка данных на сервер c#

Tags: c#, асинхронность

Требуется:

*Открывается окно загрузки, начинается отправка данных на сервер, через три секунды окно загрузки закрывается, открывается главное.*

Сейчас сделал так:

```
Timer tmr;
private void Loading_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tmr = new Timer();
    tmr.Interval = 3000;
    tmr.Start();
    tmr.Tick += tmr_Tick;
}

void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tmr.Stop();
    Main mf = new Main();
    mf.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

Нужно вставить этот код так, чтобы он не затормаживал работу программы, или делал это по минимуму:

```
string url = "http://site.com/";
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    var pars = new NameValueCollection();
    pars.Add("format", "json");
    var response = webClient.UploadValues(url, pars); 
}
```

Comment: Может, для этого отдельный поток создать?

Comment: [UploadValuesAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms144246(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: или даже [UploadValuesTaskAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh472354(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Видимо, код будет такой:

```
private void Loading_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        /*log t.Exception*/
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
}

private async Task LoadAsync()
{
    string url = "http://site.com/";
    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        var pars = new NameValueCollection();
        pars.Add("format", "json");

        byte[] response = await webClient.UploadValuesTaskAsync(url, pars).ConfigureAwait(true);

        /*we are on UI thread*/
    }

    Main mf = new Main();
    mf.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

Что тут происходит:

1. Создаем async функцию для скачивания.
2. Используем предложенный метод, но асинхронно. Как только WebClient почуствует, что надо ждать, он сназу же сменит поток.
3. В конце открываем главное окно
4. Если асинхронная функция упадет, но у нас будут проблемы (зависит от версии .Net), а потому не забываем подписаться на падения и отлогировать)

Comment: А почему `ContinueWith`, а не так: http://pastebin.com/4Ar3amAW? Или вообще так: http://pastebin.com/iQuhwMRy

Comment: @VladD, Вы правы. Можно и так, однако часто метод выше (точнее, очень похожий на него) выносится как Extension метод "SuppressExceptions" или что-то в этом духе. И в идеале мы считаем, что все методы с Task могут бросать исключение. Если мы делаем Wait, то подавление не требуется. Если делаем в стиле "запустил и забыл", то в том методе, где async стыкуется с sync мы и обрабатываем исключение. Однако в любом случае это вопрос стиля, результат у моего метода и обоих Ваших будет абсолютно одинаков.

Comment: Как `SuppressExceptions` такой метод, конечно, вполне хорош, вопрос снимается.